# Promise all, getting redundant result

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, es6-promise

I've a `Promise` array. While passing it to `Promise.all`, it returns unusual response. Okay this is the minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
const promiseChain = [1, 2, 3].map(number => new Promise(resolve, reject) => {
  // Calling an function with callback.
  getMyObj(number, (err, myObj) => {
     if (err) reject(err);
     else {
       // Comment 1
       // Here I'm able to log the desired result both number & myObj.
       resolve({ number, myObj });
     }
  })
});

Promise.all(promiseChain).then((results) => {
  results.forEach(result => {
     // Comment 2
     // Here number is correct for all objects. 
     // But, myObj is same for all the numbers.
  });
});
```

Check the comments. What I'm able to log in place of comments are as follows,

Comment 1:

```
{ number: 1, myObj: {a: 1}}
{ number: 2, myObj: {b: 2}}
{ number: 3, myObj: {c: 3}}
```

Comment 2:

```
{ number: 1, myObj: {c: 3}}
{ number: 2, myObj: {c: 3}}
{ number: 3, myObj: {c: 3}}
```

Here, What am I doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: Your if/else syntax is wonky, not sure if that is causing your issue?

Comment: Change your map method to a function instead of the arrow syntax, I _think_ that's the issue

Comment: well we don't know what you are doing inside `getMyObj` . This is obviously the source of your troubles, not the rest of your code.

Comment: @George that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @mpm I'm doing a db call to fetch an obj that's all.

Comment: @vicke4 Your problem has nothing to do with the code you wrote in your question, period. Show us in your code how `myObj` is created, how are  `{a: 1}` `{b: 2}` `{c: 3}` built?

Comment: Try to use `console.table` instead of `console.log` you're probably mutating something.

Comment: @mpm So, `getMyObj` function will be like this, https://i.imgur.com/aKBrmIz.png

Comment: @mpm apparently, I was doing more than what I showed in the image. On every iteration, I was passing an object to the `getMyObj` function. Which I was modifying and returning. Here, obviously the issue was the way I was doing things. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@mpm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/750852/mpm), first of all thanks much for your effort.

[@HMR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1641941/hmr), dude thanks for the hint. Without it I'd have wasted several hours.

What I had to do to fix the issue was deep clone. I used lodash [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#cloneDeep,) function to fix the issue. So, right below `comment 1` doing the following fixed the issue.

```
resolve({ number, myObj: _.cloneDeep(myObj) });
```